# Is there a way to count the number of actual replaces when using replaceAll in OO Basic?

Tags: openoffice-basic

Considering the example for search & replace of specific uk-to-us words from the [Editing Text Documents OO Wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Editing_Text_Documents):

```
Dim I As Long
Dim Doc As Object
Dim Replace As Object
Dim BritishWords(5) As String
Dim USWords(5) As String

BritishWords() = Array("colour", "neighbour", "centre", "behaviour", _
   "metre", "through")
USWords() = Array("color", "neighbor", "center", "behavior", _
   "meter", "thru")

Doc = ThisComponent
Replace = Doc.createReplaceDescriptor

For I = 0 To 5
  Replace.SearchString = BritishWords(I)
  Replace.ReplaceString = USWords(I)
  Doc.replaceAll(Replace)
Next I
```

Question: is there a way to get the count of actual replacement that has been made ? (if any) I don't mind the individual count for each term, but just globally – i.e. if, say, the original text included 2 occurences for 'colour' and 1 for 'behaviour', in the end to get the number 3 (purpose: to report this number to user as info via `MsgBox`).

Comment: I found an indirect way, in that counting all occurrences *prior* to effective replacement, keeping for later the count number in a hope that the replacement will be successful; rather a workaround than a true solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the example at https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/XReplaceable.html, the number found is returned.

```
Dim TotalFound As Long
TotalFound = 0
...
  TotalFound = TotalFound + Doc.replaceAll(Replace)
Next I
MsgBox "Replaced " & TotalFound & " occurrences"
```

Result: `Replaced 3 occurrences`